# Android emulator shows blank when debuging

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am building an app and have hit a bit of a bug when running my app. In order to troubleshoot this I tried debugging, rather than running. However, whenever I do this, the screen of the emulator shows all black apar from the app name bit at the top.

Anybody know why this might be?

**For some reason, I can now see the layout, so thanks for your help. However, the "variables" eclipse window shows blank, and this is the bit I really want to see. But thanks for your help.**

Comment: post error stacktrace from Logcat window..

Comment: I don't get anything in the logcat.

Comment: Have you put any breakpoints in your `Activity` `onCreate()` method?

Comment: No, but I did notice that the debugger got to the `setContentView(R.layout.main);` line (it was highlighted) and then got no further.

Comment: @ACarter The black screen(with only the title) happens because you don't get out from the `onCreate()` method so you don't have something to show on the emulator/phone yet. How do you actually debug the app, where are the breakpoints, other information about the debug process? Also in the `Logcat` on the left on `All messages(No filters)` and see what you get, errors etc.

Comment: I don't have any breakpoints. I debugged it by going to "Run>Debug" in eclipse?

Comment: @ACarter `Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock! ` means that your `Activity` took to much to load(you can find more with a search on StackOverflow). With Run>Debug without the breakpoints you practically run the application as it is. If you want to stop the application and see the variables set a breakpoint on the line you want to stop(a double click on the bar next to the line in the code editor), then use `step into`, `step over`, `step return`.

Answer (score 1):

post your main activity code / androidmanifest xml code,

Restart your eclipse... it would Definitely show something in your logcat window since your application has started on emulator...